# Trying to make a web service with a javafx client that computes loans. It isn't working out

Tags: java, web-services, javafx, netbeans, webservice-client

So this is the very first time I'm learning and doing things regarding web services. What with current global events and my instructor hardly ever responding to my attempts at reaching out, I (and my classmates) are pretty much on our own. Our current assignment is to create a web service that has two remote methods to compute the monthly and annual payments of a loan. A client is then made to prompt the user to actually enter in the numbers that will be used. I, with my text book, worked on this assignment and are still currently doing so. The problem is is that my text book is using older versions of NetBeans while I'm on the newest version (11.1). So I'm already fighting against version differences alongside just trying to comprehend and finish this assignment.

Currently when I run the actual web service by itself it does not give me the option to individually put in the actual numbers to compute and if I enter anything in, it'll just give me that number with an error.

The client, when ran, doesn't display anything. Not even a window. What am I doing wrong here and what are some ways I can fix this?

Here's the Web Service:

```
package chapter39;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;

@WebService(serviceName = "ComputeLoan")
public class ComputeLoan {

    int loanAmount;
    int numOfYears;
    int annInterestRate;
    int mPayment;
    int aPayment;

    @WebMethod(operationName = "MonthlyPayment")
    public int monthlyPayment (String txt) {

        mPayment = loanAmount * (annInterestRate / numOfYears);

        System.out.println("Your loan amount is: " + loanAmount);
        System.out.println("Your number of years is: " + numOfYears);
        System.out.println("Your your interest rate is: " + annInterestRate);
        System.out.println("Your monthly payment is: " + mPayment);

        return mPayment;

    }

    @WebMethod(operationName = "AnnualPayment")
    public int annualPayment (String txt) {

        aPayment = (loanAmount * annInterestRate) / numOfYears;

        System.out.println("Your loan amount is: " + loanAmount);
        System.out.println("Your number of years is: " + numOfYears);
        System.out.println("Your your interest rate is: " + annInterestRate);
        System.out.println("Your monthly payment is: " + aPayment);

        return aPayment;
```

And here's the client:

```
package chapter39;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import myWebservice.ComputeLoan;
import myWebservice.ComputeLoan_Service;


public class ComputeLoanApp extends Application {

    private ComputeLoan_Service service = new ComputeLoan_Service();
    private ComputeLoan proxy = service.getComputeLoanPort();
    private Button btCalculate = new Button("Calculate"); 
    private TextField tfLoan = new TextField();  
    private TextField tfInterest = new TextField();
    private TextField tfYear = new TextField();
    private TextField tfMonthly = new TextField();
    private TextField tfAnnual = new TextField();


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();  
              gridPane.setHgap(5);  
              gridPane.add(new Label("Loan Amount"), 0, 0);  
              gridPane.add(new Label("Interest Rate"), 0, 1);
              gridPane.add(new Label("Number of Years"), 0, 2);  
              gridPane.add(new Label("Monthly Payment"), 0, 3);  
              gridPane.add(new Label("Annual Payment"), 0, 4);  
              gridPane.add(new Label("Calculate"), 0, 5);  

              gridPane.add(tfLoan, 1, 0);  
              gridPane.add(tfInterest, 1, 1);
              gridPane.add(tfYear, 1, 2); 
              gridPane.add(tfMonthly, 1, 3);
              gridPane.add(tfAnnual, 1, 4);
              gridPane.add(btCalculate, 1, 5);  


              // Create a scene and place the pane in the stage 
              Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 250, 250);  
              primaryStage.setTitle("ComputeLoanApp"); // Set the stage title 
              primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage 
              primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage 

              btCalculate.setOnAction(e -> getPayment());
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public void getPayment() {
        int mLoan = proxy.monthlyPayment(tfLoan.getText().trim());
        int mInterest = proxy.monthlyPayment(tfInterest.getText().trim());
        int mYear = proxy.monthlyPayment(tfYear.getText().trim());

        int aLoan = proxy.annualPayment(tfLoan.getText().trim());
        int aInterest = proxy.annualPayment(tfInterest.getText().trim());
        int aYear = proxy.annualPayment(tfYear.getText().trim());

        int mPayment = proxy.monthlyPayment(tfMonthly.getText().trim());
        int aPayment = proxy.annualPayment(tfMonthly.getText().trim());        


        tfMonthly.setText(Integer.toString(mPayment));
        tfAnnual.setText(Integer.toString(aPayment));
}

    }
```

Comment: For the client, it doesn't do anything because your `main()` method is empty. You need `Application.launch(args);` in there. That should at least give you something to work with (error messages or a UI, etc). On the web service side (I am not a web service expert; I usually use Spring for REST APIs), surely it should be stateless? And anyway, you do nothing at all with the value (`txt`) passed to the methods. Probably you just need to start there by thinking about what each method's role is in the context of a http request/response.

Comment: You should probably separate this into two questions, BTW, and separate your work in general into two different parts. You can get the web service running and test it with a REST client (browser plugin or curl, or similar). Test your UI out with a local class that does the calculations first, then incorporate the web service communication once you have that working.